How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to an application-specific script?
I've created a Javascript filed as Submit form JXA in ~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Numbers.
Submit form JXA appears as a menu item in the Scripts menu when Numbers is front window. Clicking this menu item runs the script as expected.

But trying to assign a Keyboard shortcut to Submit form JXA is eluding me.
The screenshot below shows that I have tried making it a Keyboard shortcut for Numbers and then All Applications and Finder but neither triggers the script.
(I don't know which o my keyboard shortcut definitions is showing up in the Scripts menu above)


I use FastScripts for this purpose.
